# Project linked to adobe xd and zeplin and unsubscribe

Tags: adobe, adobe-xd, zeplin

I got XD file from designer. So I tried to open the file but I didn't have an adobe xd account! So I subscribed to the free trial version of Adobe CC (creative cloud) where you can use the adobe xd app as a temporary measure. But the free trial is only seven days old. So I needed a way to view the xd file even after that. Zeplin is free to use, so I installed zeplin, create a project, and exported file from adobe xd to zeplin.

I wonder if I can still view the zeplin project I created after exporting from adobe xd after the free trial of adobe account is over.